# PWM fans causing temp sensor erroneus values (interference?)

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, temperature-sensor

I am learning Arduino programming and my current project for real use is to connect 10-17 PC chassis PWM fans to be temperature controlled by the arduino.

So, I have connected the fans exactly as in the picture.
Taken from https://www.racedepartment.com/threads/easy-diy-wind-simulator-for-assetto-corsa.133999/

[image: PWM Fan connection diagram]

The temperature sensor is a TMP36 (included in the official Arduino beginner's kit). It is connected to +5V and GND on the Arduino Uno R3. Middle pin is the output and is connected to A0 on the Uno.

Temperature readings seem to work well up until the point the fans start spinning. When they do, the output pin on the TMP36 sensor outputs junk values. Such as 0V or 700mV and it fluctuates up and down if I try probing it with a multimeter. When fans some to a stop however, the output once again stabilizes to a fairly correct value.

I am no expert in electronics interference, but electric motors I suppose cause some electrical noise? I had hoped that PC Chassis fans would already have electric components inside the hub to prevent such though...
Currently I am trying to run 2 fans at the same time but I wish to use 10-17 later once this works.

The fans I am using are Arctic 92mm PWM Rev 02.

I have checked the datasheet (https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/TemperatureSensor.pdf) for TMP36 (TO-92 package type) and tried adding a ceramic 0.1µF capacitor between +5V and GND and also add resistor of varying values to the output pin. I believe I got some stabilization out of it but not  enough. Especially when the fans start spinnig faster than 20% duty cycle on pwm it starts to flip out.

I have tried to disconnect power to fans to check if PWM signal may cause it too, but this is not the case as the TMP36 remain stable with PWM on but fans disconnected.

Can someone please help me with explaining what is probably going on and how I can mitigate the problem in a preferably easy way? Do I need to add diodes, capacitors, resistors? Where? Or should I change to a different temperature sensor (which)?

Thankful for help!

Comment: Quick thought:   It may be that trying to do both is causing problems.  That is, you may be using the same processor resource(s) for both features.  Like a timer or a serial port.  Just because an Arduino program compiles doesn't mean that the libraries you include will work with one another.

Comment: BTW, you are using a second power supply to power the Arduino, right?  I say this as I realize 2 things.  1) I assume you have copied a working project exactly.  So there is precedence that the included libraries work together.  -and- 2) There is no second power supply in the diagram.  I think the original author just assumed there would be one.

Comment: @st2000 Hmmm, I only use PWM (analogWrite) and AnalogRead to read the temperature value. It feels like a very "simple case" for it to collide? That would cause lots of problems in projects of all kinds then. I tried to use an LDR instead of a TMP36 and fetch analog values and that worked like a charm.

The Arduino is powered via USB (PC connection). The fans are powered via external wall adapter as in the picture. So power for fans is drawn from the power adapter.

Comment: The LDR would have needed a pull up or pull down resistor.  (Did you use one?) Where as, I assume, the TMP36 would not.  I didn't look at the TMP36 spec, my bad, I didn't realize it developed an analog output.  I thought it was one of the common temperature probes which communicated over an I2C bus. Double check that you have connected to the correct pins of the TMP36.  Note the TO92 case is a bottom view whereas the other case views are from the top.

Comment: @st2000 You are correct, yes I had a resistor in series with the LDR (10kOhm) while the TMP36 did not need one (although in the datasheet I then found a section towards the end regarding high inductive loads showing a capacitor of 01µF and a resistor of 750 Ohm). Maybe is stailized things a tiny bit but as soon as fans spin up above 20% or so the TMP36 starts acting up. The connections to the TMP36 should be correct because it works fine when fans are not spinning. I feel that there's something missing, like some capacitor or diode or something for the fans maybe?

Comment: This is turning into guess work.  The series resistance and cap are likely to mitigate noise by matching the impedance of a long cable between the ADC and the TMP36.  Just keep it short for now. A foot / decimeter would be fine.  I suspect the current draw of the fans at speed is dripping the voltage of the fan power supply and dragging the laptop's USB power source with it resulting in unexpected readings.  Check to see if the power supply your are using is double the sum of the expected fan currents.  Also, try connecting only 1 fan to see if it will run as expected.

Comment: I suspect you will point out that the LDR / resistor divider had no problems controlling the fans to the desired fast speed.  If this truly is the case, I might guess that the impedance of the LDR / resistor divider is lower than that of the TMP36.  That in such a case, a little noise can manifest its self as larger voltage swings and more erratic ADC samples.   If true, that is, if the noise is random and the average reading accurate enough for this project, consider solving this problem in software.  Take the average of the readings and use that to control the fans.

Comment: @st2000 It is correct that the voltage values I got from reading the LDR were consistent, so I could set a PWM duty cycle based on lighting conditions in a consistent manner. I can't really take an average of the TMP36 though because when the fans are spinning and it gets affected by some interference, the output pin gives 0V or anything inbetween that and say 700mV and with a multimeter I can see that the output pin voltage jumps around all the time. Until I stop the fans, that is. Can I use a resistive temperature sensor instead (like the LDR for Light)? in so, which one has linear response?

Comment: Did you check the fan power supply is 2 x the sum of the peak current demand of the fans?  (Fans rated at 0.8A so both are 1.6A so 2 x means should use a power supply that can supply 3.2A.)  Or experiment w/only 1 fan - but use a power supply that can supply 1.6A.

Comment: Currently I use a power bank which can supply 12V. But the fans are rated 0.16A (not 1.6A  that would be raally powerful fans :) ). So with both fans at max speed I get 0.32A @ 12V. But I get sensor problems for anything above 20% speed when the two fans only draw very little current. I don't think that the power supply is too weak but I will try with another PSU.
If I had an oscilloscope I would be able to see if I have some distortion of voltage on the input to the sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem, I solved it. Turns out is was a bad PSU. Buying a new, higher quality one made everything work. So the issue was high ripple I suspect, or at least high enough when applying some load (which is why I noticed that things got worse after the fans started spinning at greater than 20% duty cycle) for the temperature sensor to flip out.